# Get draggable widgets on Edit Post page

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, post-meta

Is it possible to get the widgets with settings (just as widgets.php page) on the **Edit post** (like attached image) ?

There i can define a custom sidebar in post meta. However how to get the list of widgets to drag in the sidebar.

[image]